# My website is logged out everytime i come back

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, asp.net-core

I'm working on an asp.net core 2 web application. For some reason, when I don't enter for a while (i.e. 1 hour) it is logged out

this is my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Ojete.UI.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Since I don't have a clue about how is this happening, I don't know which another part of the code should I post. Sorry about that!

Comment: Could you add the part where you configure authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, please

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // here you can change timeout
});
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1389 - more details.